# My discord bot keeps spamming after I send a message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Everytime I send a mesaage in my discord server my bot spams and pings itself while it does it.

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'Faketoken';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.content = "hello"){
        msg.reply('Hello!');
    }
})

bot.login(token);
```

I think the problem is at bot.on('message',

Comment: You are trying to check equality with a single '=' which is an assignment. Since that's not None it's evaluated as True every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack-Overflow!

So first off to fix your problem: you need this simple line: `if(message.author.bot) return;` at the start of the `message` event. **why**? Well the bot is *responding* to itself.

It sees your message, sends a response. Sees it's own response, assumes it's a new message. And sends another response. Over & over again. 
That line checks if the message that is sees came from a bot, if so: *don't do anything*

The second issue is right here: `if(msg.content = "hello")` This is **setting** `msg.content` to "hello". **NOT** checking if it matches with "hello" Replace it with: `if(msg.content === "hello")`

Comment: Thank you! It stopped my bot from spamming and it only responded to the command.